# MediaRecorder fails on stop and file isn't playable when using surface video source

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

`MediaRecorder` fails on stop and file isn't playable and its size is only 70-110 kb when using `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);`

when I stop video recording I get next error

```
MediaRecorder: stop failed: -1007
```

I tested that this issue happens on Marshmallow 6.0.1 device

but it works fine for Nougat device

seems the same issue but with no answer here [MediaRecorder stop failed Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618378/mediarecorder-stop-failed-android)

**UPDATE** I rebooted my Marshmallow 6.0.1 device (Xiaomi Redmi 4 Prime/Pro) and it works now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted my Marshmallow 6.0.1 device (Xiaomi Redmi 4 Prime/Pro) and it works now

But it can stop working again very soon...

**UPDATE** this issue is serious Android bug: [MediaRecorder and VideoSource.SURFACE, stop failed: -1007 (a serious Android bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332386/mediarecorder-and-videosource-surface-stop-failed-1007-a-serious-android-bug)